# Qual è il senso di "coccola" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Aveva letture raffinate, viaggiava molto, la sua imponente genealogia teatrale (figlia di Margherita Bagni, nipote di Ermete Zacconi) ne faceva la **coccola** del mondo delle scene, l'autorizzava a darsi del tu con Laura Adani, Giulio Stival, la Maltagliati!

Il testo si riferisce a Nora Ricci, compagna d'accademia di Gassman.

Non capisco qual è il senso di "coccola" in questo brano. Ho cercato il vocabolo in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che può significare una carezza o un gesto di tenerezza o affettuosità, ma questo non sembra avere senso nel testo precedente. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: cosa vuol dire "coccola" nel brano sopra citato?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La *coccola* è come dire, in modo colloquiale, la *coccolata*, la *vezzeggiata*. Il sostantivo che indica il gesto, dunque, passa a significare una persona che riceve quel gesto. Un altro modo per dire *coccola* secondo questo significato è *cocca*.

Comment: Ho visto che, nel romanzo *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante, appare appunto il termine "cocca" con questo significato: «Poiché il professore di religione faceva continue filippiche contro i comunisti, contro il loro ateismo, io mi sentii spinta a reagire, non so bene se dal mio affetto nei confronti di Pasquale, che comunista s’era sempre dichiarato, o semplicemente perché percepii che tutto il male che il prete diceva dei comunisti mi riguardava direttamente in quanto **cocca** della comunista per eccellenza, la professoressa Galiani.»

Comment: Mi pare interessante poiché tale significato di "cocca" non sembra trovarsi nei dizionari.

Answer (score 0):

È ovviamente una metafora. Nora Ricci era appartenente a una "imponente genealogia teatrale", un fatto ben conosciuto dai compagni artisti... Tenendo conto dell'appartenenza familiare, lei "scivolava" con tale dimestichezza nel mondo delle scene quasi come una carezza, una coccola... Questo si riconferma anche con la frase "...l'autorizzava a darsi del tu con Laura Adani, Giulio Stival, la Maltagliati!".